# SpecFlow Jenkins Run Failing looking for NewtonSoft v9.0.0.0

Tags: specflow, specrun

I am setting up a new project on Jenkins and I am having a slight issue. The build is successful but when specrun begins, all tests are ignored and it is throwing the below error.

> TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.SpecRunException: At least one test thread aborted. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

My App.config I have added the below to support the new version:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

I still throw the error. I have uninstalled, re-installed and searched for 9.0.0.0 but nothing. I have 9.0.0.1 in private assemplies as well as an old v6. There are similar posts out there on StackOverflow and other sites but I have not been able to get this to work. I have also tried executing from command line. Any suggestions?

- SpecFlow v1.78
- MSBuild v3.78
- SpecRun.Runner v3.1.44
- SpecRun.SpecFlow.3-1-0 v3.144

There was a bug in upgrading to current so I had to rollback.

Comment: Is there a reference in your project to the NuGet package? Are you doing a `nuget restore` prior to building the solution?

Comment: Hey Greg. Thanks for the help. No references to the 9.0.0.0 dll, There is a reference to the new version. It was added as a nuget package. This makes me think that one of the other packages is referencing a specific version vs the nuget package?

Comment: also the frustrating thing is I loaded up Jenkins locally and everything runs fine.

Comment: Try running `nuget locals all -delete` on your machine to see if that makes a difference, and delete all the stuff in the "packages" folder in the solution. If that doesn't give you a consistent failure, try uninstalling NewtonSoft.Json and then install version 9. See if that helps. If that works, try updating to v12 after that.

Comment: Greg - Thanks for your help. I ended up posting this on the SpecFlow Github site. It looks like it may be a defect. I was able to run via vstest.console.exe so not sure why that works and specrun does not. Good times. I did run your suggestion and I even used baregrep to look for the Newtsonsoft call in config files. I saw some outdated references but no luck on anything,

Comment: How did you fix this?

Comment: Frank - I ran via vstest console for awhile but there was a bug. I rolled back to the previous version of specflow and it worked. I am running latest version now with no issues.